# Tracing a point on a rotating circle

Tags: trigonometry, functions

[image: Find F of X]

I have a large circle and a small circle as shown in the image. The distance between the centers of those circles. The Larger circle is rotating about it's center while traveling in direction D such that it travels its circumference in 1 revolution. There is a point on the smaller circle called X. I need a function that can calculate the path of x (for graphing purposes).

Is there a mathematical formula for this? If not then what group of math formulas could be used to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid) for more information (especially look in the Related Curves section). In particular, this appears to be a *curtate cycloid*, based on my reading of your question.

Comment: Calculate as a Cycloid, many thanks.